# How do I use dataLayer.get to find an argument inside the Google Tag dataLayer?

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager, google-datalayer

I used `console.table(dataLayer)` to get the index value from the dataLayer, but I'm curious, is there a way to get an event name that is inside an argument and store it in a variable? I'm trying to pull out `score_7` from the string `target|all|conversion|site|score_7`

```
dataLayer[21]
Arguments(3) ['event', 'target|all|conversion|site|score_7', {…}, callee: (...), gtm.uniqueEventId: 23563, Symbol(Symbol.iterator): ƒ]
    0: "event"
    1: "target|all|conversion|site|score_7"
    2: {send_to: 'XX-123456789', non_interaction: true}
    callee: (...)
    gtm.uniqueEventId: 23563
    length: 3
    Symbol(Symbol.iterator): ƒ values()
    get callee: ƒ ()
    set callee: ƒ ()
    [[Prototype]]: Object
```

Comment: @faridghar any support you could give on this one? I'm stuck with no solution after spending time on google search.